# Site lags on scroll, why?

Tags: scroll, lag

site here: http://innobo.johanohrvall.se/

When you scroll up or down, everything lags and turn white and I cant figure out why. Have anyone else had this problem?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that will help the lagging is using smaller images, resizing and compressing them. Images on the site are upwards of 2MB, which is HUGE and hurting your performance.

Your site got rated 0/100 on web performance. I have a feeling if you get that up to 70, you will notice it won't lag and images won't be white. Source: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Finnobo.johanohrvall.se%2F&tab=desktop